# Google Colab - Execute a bash command from python string

Tags: python

I wrote an code which contain

```
str1 = "word1"
str2 = "word2"
str3 = "word3"

var1 = str("./e " + str1 + "/" + str2 + "/" + str3)

#NOW I NEED TO RUN A BASH COMMAND:

!cd bin && var1

#LIKE THIS: "cd bin && ./e str1/str2/str3"
```

How can I do this? Please help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$var1 should work

```
str1 = "word1"
str2 = "word2"
str3 = "word3"

var1 = str("./e " + str1 + "/" + str2 + "/" + str3)

#NOW I NEED TO RUN A BASH COMMAND:

!cd bin && $var1

!echo $var1 #echos./e word1/word2/word3 whish you desired
```

Comment: i get this error : /bin/bash: ./e: No such file or directory

Comment: final command is `cd bin && ./e word1/word2/word3` if this is giving an error then there is problem with command are you sure you want to execute that ?this example just shows how you can you python variable  to execute shell command in colab

Answer (score 0):

You can use os module

```
 import os
 str1 = "word1"
 str2 = "word2"
 str3 = "word3"

 var1 = str("./e " + str1 + "/" + str2 + "/" + str3)

 os.system(f"!cd bin && {var1}")
```

Comment: that's working but i don't see the output of my ./e file